PWM with PIC817 driving MOSFET seems to be too slow (LED dimming)
I want to drive a MOSFET (IRFZ44N) with an optocoupler (PC817) to control the brightness of an 50 W  12 V LED. The PWM is generated by an ESP8266, 1 kHz.
Following schematic is used:

In general it works, but PWM set to 10% does not result in 10% brightness of the LED. I expect it be much darker.
I have a circuit to compare with, where the brightness of the LED is as expected with 10% PWM:

Why does the circuit with the optocoupler does not get as dark (fast switching?) like the one with the two transistors?
When I understood the datasheet of the PC817 correct, it should be able to handle up to 80 kHz?
Thanks in advance!
Edit: In the first schematic (a later version of my project) I added the two capacitors at the output to get rid of the switching 1 kHz noises. The Schottky diode is there because I expect the user to use a relays as well, but then without the ability to adjust brightness by PWM.

Under what condition did the datasheet suggest 80kHz bandwidth? What does this suggest compared to your circuit, and, with respect to the duty range you expect from it? || Do you actually need an opto? The circuit shows common grounds. Is there a simpler solution you may be overlooking?

While the text says the opto is PIC817, is the part actually a PC817?

My fault! It is indeed the PC817, not PIC817 that was mistyped be me. i corrected it in my question text

Why the optocoupler? You have shared ground on both sides of it.

@winny I used the optocoupler because someone recommended me to do so to add some protection to the ESP8266 for the case when some current flows there when it shouldnt. I am just a hobbyist when it comes to electronics, so "it will isolate the µC" sounds good to me

It won't isolate anything with the grounds connected. Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease

@winny thank you! that post makes things pretty clear and understandable to me. So I went into the same trap :)

Very common trap. Too common. Aim for a shared ground with solid ground plane unless very special purpose or laws prohibiting you from doing so

You are discharging the gate too slow through 10k.
Change this 10k to PNP transistor:


Even with a booster, the opto itself is limited to a couple 10s of µs in this configuration.

@TimWilliams Maybe the problem is miller effect, rising drain potential --> rising gate potential, causing very slow turn off. If so, then this booster will certainly help. I feel that 20µs is still very short compared to the 1000µs PWM cycle time, and shouldn't be so noticeable, so I don't think opto-coupler speed is the real problem.

@TimWilliams rather, I don't think opto-coupler speed is the biggest problem.

@SimonFitch More like 50us at 10k: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf Fig.13. Though I'm not sure what they mean by "Ic = 2mA", implying Vcc > 20V maybe, but, the whole point is Ic varies, I don't know. IRFZ44N is around 40nC or 4nF equivalent, 4nF * 10k = 40us time constant, say 90us 10-90% rise/fall, so both are relevant.

So when I understood it correct, lowering the pull down resistor might already help? Or is the PNP Transistor to add mandatory to solve the problem?

As I learned from @winnys  answer (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716110/pwm-with-pic817-driving-mosfet-seems-to-be-too-slow-led-dimming?noredirect=1#comment1905000_716110) the opto wouldnt protect the µC as i thought it would. So  I will trhow it out and replace it with some other MOSFET driver circuit.

Just for the notes: i replaced the 10K pull down resistor with a 4.7K and things are better now - not ideal but noticably better. But as already wrote,  I will replace the opto with some other driver
Thanks to everyone! :)
