Why does the STM32F030 hang when the solenoid Lock is activated?
The circuit consists of a STM32F030 and several 5 V relays, which are connected to the coil to open the door. The input voltage is from 18 V which is fed from a 220 to 18 V transformer (not switching transformer). When the relay is activated for 0.5 seconds, it activates the solenoid Lock, and at this time, the input voltage drops and the micro hangs. The micro watchdog is active, but it activates the micro LED that is connected to the micro. It is unwanted. The board works normally in typical without coil. I used a diode bridge circuit and a 2200 uF capacitor for the input, and the circuit is stabilized, but it still hangs sometimes. LM2596-5V switching circuit for 5 V and 3.3 V regulator is also AMS1117. Is it useful if I make the regulator linear like 7805?


Please post a schematic.

No, embed it into your question.

Please take the Tour and check out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking. Off-site links other than datasheets makes the question difficult for the reader. Please EMBED your schematic as an image or draw it using the built in tool by clicking Edit and then on the schematic symbol

Could be layout too. Do you have a ground plane? How many PCB layers? What happens if you just add more ceramic capacitors to all Vcc (5 and 3.3 V) pins and ground?

Why use such a high input voltage if you only need 5 V for your circuit?

This sounds like the crux of your problem: When the relay is activated for 0.5 seconds, it activates the coil, and at this time, the input voltage drops and the micro hangs

Also, your optocouplers are of no use since you share ground on both sides. Please see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease

Thanks for optocouupler tip. My board is 2 layers and size is 8.4 * 5 cm. space for add capacitors is not exit. input is 12 to 24 volts. board work good with AC and DC. Just when solenoid Lock connect to relay, drop voltage input and microcontroller does not have specific behavior. If add a Inductor to input is a good?

You can solder the capacitors on top of the existing ones, and deadbug to component legs. Do you have a solid ground plane? What does Vcc look like on your scope when you switch the relay?

Have you the correct mix of capacitors in close proximity to the AMS1117 where you appear to be deriving 3 volts from 5v ?

Why are you using such ancient regulators in the first place? Iirc this is the first generation simple switcher from the previous millennium. As for AMS1117, it seems rather infamous for it's poor quality. Iirc it goes bananas if you don't provide an output cap with a very specific ESR.

I don't have space to add a capacitor, also I haven't included a polygon for the ground (I want to put some capacitors for the 3.3 V input). The voltage drops from 20 volts to 9 volts for a moment. Where I am, electronic parts are not easily available, and therefore the number of choices is very few and almost all parts are fake. In the new version, I want to include a polygon for the ground, but do you know a circuit to reduce the momentary voltage drop.
