driving 24V relay from 3.3V controller
I’m trying to actuate relays using a 3.3V microcontroller. To do this, I used an optocoupler to translate the signal from 3.3V to 24V, while also providing optical isolation. When I send a HIGH command from the controller, I hear the relay click, but there’s no voltage at the relay contacts when I measure them with a multimeter. The reverse is also true.
I’ve attached the schematic. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?


if it clicks but doesn't connect, it needs more coil power.

is circuit which I done is correct?

Usually if a relay clicks the contacts are switching. Are you sure you're measuring the output correctly?

I'm measuring between Q0 and GNDINT

With ohmmeter or voltmeter?

voltmeter in DC voltage mode

"I used an optocoupler to translate the signal from 3.3V to 24V" Why? Your NPN will do that for you. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease

You are measuring across the normally open contacts of the relay, when the relay is activated they are connected together so they are a short circuit. The voltage across a short circuit should be zero. When not activated the contacts will be open and they will have a voltage across them that depends on what they are connected to. It sounds like you are seeing exactly what you should see considering the circuit.
If you want to switch voltage to a device there are several ways to do it.
You can do high-side switching where the positive voltage is switched:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Or you can do low-side switching where the negative is switched. Since you have the relay connected to GNDINT already this might be your best option.

simulate this circuit
For a two terminal device it shouldn't matter which side you switch, but if the device being switched has other connections that may have a path to ground you would want to switch the positive side.
UPDATE concerning question of using circuit for AC voltage:
For switching AC mains voltage you would need to not have any of the relay contacts connected to GNDINT or any other part of your existing circuit, they should be dry contacts, only switching the external AC circuit.

simulate this circuit
230 VAC is considered a lethal voltage. You have to be very careful with any design dealing with mains voltage, there are circuit board clearances to prevent arcing and other things you have to worry about, and there may be certifications needed if it's going to be a commercial product. If you do not have any experience working with these voltages you need to get help from someone who does.

If I send HIGH, I hear click sound, but the voltage across relay contacts is Zero, When I send LOW, again I hear click sound, still my voltage across contacts is Zero

@priya What you have in the relay is a set of switch contacts, that's all a relay is, an electromagnetically activated switch.  You have the switch common connected to GNDINT which I'm assuming is at ground potential. the NO contact will then be grounded when the relay is activated. When it's not activated the NO contact will only have voltage on it if it's connected to some source of voltage such as a pullup resistor. If you don't have anything connected to it then you'll read no voltage. If you do have something connected to it you'll have to tell us what that is.

So for testing purpose, I have connected relay output to power ON capacitive Proximity sensor (10-30VDC PS), So when relay is activated , the sensor is not powering ON. I connected positive terminal of sensor to NO and negative terminal to GNDINT.

@priya You are putting the relay contacts in parallel with the load, they need to be in series between the load and it’s power source. I will add a schematic to my answer when I get to my desktop computer a little later.

Thanks for the schematic, The circuit now behaves in Active LOW Logic , I tested the relay in low-side switching configuration because the COM terminal is already connected to GNDINT of 24V DC supply. I need another clarification too, this relay is capable of handling 230V AC Load, since COM terminal is already connected to GNDINT, is it possible to connect AC Load too.. still not tested to avoid a possible damage to the board.

I got one reference circuit from net. I want my circuit to behave like ACTIVE HIGH, wherein high command makes relay to close the contact and Low command makes it to open, I need you concurrence whether the attached schematic will do my job,before going for another set of pcb fabrication. Please see schematic here

@priya - Hi, (a) You originally posted the above comment as an answer. However since it is asking a question it should not have been posted as an answer. Therefore I have moved it to here, as you're trying to ask a question to GodJihyo. For the future please note that this technique can be used to upload an image to get an image link, which can be used in a comment (since comments don't display images inline). (b) You said that you got that schematic from the internet. Please provide the original source link - see here. TY

@priya Yes, the circuit you linked is active high. As for connecting a 230 VAC load to the relay, you can't do that with COM connected to GNDINT, you would need to have COM and NO connected just to your 230 VAC circuit, and you would need to make sure that is done correctly and safely as that voltage can be lethal. There are considerations you have to take when designing a circuit board with mains voltage on it, and judging by the questions you're asking it doesn't appear that you have the experience and knowledge to be working with 230 VAC safely yet.

@priya See update in my answer.

Forgive me if I misunderstood you, but it sounds like you expect the relay to transfer something to its "output" when it activates. This is not going to happen (unless you connect the switch contacts differently), since the switch contacts are completely isolated from the coil and everything else. This is clearly depicted in the circuit symbol for a relay:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note: the dotted line indicates a magnetic coupling, to physically "pull" the switch mechanism. It is not a current path, and doesn't imply that the relay switch contacts have any electrical connection to the coil in any way.
In the left circuit, when the relay "activates" the COM and NO contacts will be physically connected together, but since there's no external connections to them, they will effectively connect some nothing to more nothing.
On the right I hope it's clear that when the relay activates (the transistor switches "on", allowing coil current to pass), then the NO contact will become physically connected to COM, and consequently to the battery's positive terminal.
In your schematic it's not clear what else is connected to the relay contacts. One seems to be grounded (COM), but the other (NO) is Q0/6.4C, which is presumably where you are measuring voltage.
When the upper relay is off, its NO terminal potential is ambiguous, since I don't know what Q0/6.4C is, but when the relay activates, the NO terminal becomes grounded also. That terminal will have 0V.
With the relay activated, you can expect the NO and COM terminals to have the same potential (since they are joined), and if you measure the voltage difference between them, you will measure 0V.
With the relay un-activated, the measured potential difference between NO and COM will depend entirely upon whatever else is connected to node Q0/6.4C.

It doesn't look to me that there is any voltage to measure- you should have an open circuit between COM and NO with the relay de-energized (no continuity) and a closed circuit (continuity) between COM and NO with the relay energized.
If you have no other voltage sources connected to the relay contacts, that is what I would expect to see. You an use an ohmmeter to measure the contacts, however ensure there is no voltage source connected to the relay contacts or you could damage your meter.
