Need a circuit for an active-low isolated switch (0.6-3.3V high level, 0V low level)
I need a circuit which would accept a voltage level on input, normally in a range 0.6V-3.3V (high level), which could drop to 0V on a button press (low level), related to common ground. The circuit should have optocoupler like output, which would be closed when input level is high, and be open when the level is low. The output would be used to simulate button press (simple mechanical switch) for another circuit. The input circuit and the circuit to be designed would have common Vcc power (12V automotive range) and common ground.
Intended use for this circuit would be to enable a dashboard button to control an aftermarket car radio, like it did with the original radio. Having hard time to choose proper components, too complicated for me now... Thanks for any suggestions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why isolated yet common gnd?  contradictory spec.

Isolation is to have minimum side effects on another circuit, and to have more options to utilize the scheme if something go wrong. Optocoupler is not strictly a requirement, an electromechanical relay would do as well.

How will an optocoupler without isolation have minimum side effects compared to no optocoupler? Please have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

D1, D2 (24V Zener), R1, C1 form a power supply that will withstand typical automotive conditions.
R2, diode-connected Q2, R4, R9 form a reference voltage of about 350mV. R8 provides a bit of hysteresis. R7, R6 and C2 filter the input and provide a defined state (on, in this case) if the input is disconnected.
The comparator is 1/2 of dual single-supply op-amp LM358. R5 controls the current through the optocoupler LED (about 8mA in this case).

This seems to be what I wanted! I only changed schematic a little - moved R5 before D3, and replaced V3 sawtooth generator with just a voltage source (V4). So, having run DC Sweep with V4 ranging from 0 to 3.3V with 0.1V stepping, I'm having the following results. This is worth trying it in hardware. Marking it as answer, thanks!

Your first paragraph is not clear.  When the button is pressed, do you want the opto output transistor to be saturated on (closed, a floating, virtual short circuit) or off (open circuit)?
If the problem really is as simple as I think you have stated, this can be done with one transistor, 2 resistors, plus the optocoupler.  This schematic is based on one interpretation of the words "open" and "closed" in the question.  If the output logic polarity is the opposite of what is needed, a 2nd transistor is added.
1 - 2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222, etc.
1 - 4.7K resistor - base pull-up
1 - 620 ohm, 0.5 W resistor - Optoisolator input diode current limiting
The Q1 base-emitter voltage (Vbe) acts as the reference voltage for a comparator action.  This is a very simple approach to the problem.  An alternate approach would use 1/2 of an LM393 dual comparator with an external diode as the voltage reference.  Schematic on request.
Note: R2 is sized for the isolator primary side current.  At 14.4 V and 20 mA, the power dissipation in R2 is 1/4 W.  This will be almost continuous dissipation when the vehicle is running, so use a 1/2 W part minimum for long-term reliability.  A small 1W part would be better.  Depending on the amount of secondary current you need to pull, and the actual optoisolator part number, you probably can increase the value or R2 for lower dissipation.
UPDATE:  New schematic with a corrected input circuit.

UPDATE:
Based on new information, here is a re-worked schematic for the same circuit with the opposite output logic polarity.  In this case, Q1 "shorts out" the opto input to keep it off.  I increased the value of R2 to decrease its static power dissipation; it now can be a 1/2 W part.
This circuit still has a relatively low input impedance.  If that causes problems, one solution is to change to a comparator or opamp IC.


Thanks, the scheme would be helpful of course, but I'll try in simulation using these parts.

See updated answer and schematic.

Thanks for the schematic. However, I need to clarify some things since I'm afraid this won't work as expected...
First, all I have on input is 1 wire, a voltage level, coming from inside car dashboard. It is "linked" to some push button (not fixable in ON state) which (used to) control the radio. As I have measured myself with a multimeter, at has some voltage in normal (released) state (0.6V-3.3V, not constant, varying with its internal tricky logic, but minimum 0.6V in sleep state), and dropping to 0V when in depressed state. It returns to 0.6-3.3V as soon as the button is released.

Second, the circuit's output needs to become conductive (don't know how to call it correctly - say, low resistance) when voltage level on input drops to zero. I would not make an assumption it gets physically connected to the ground (since I don't know implementation details). I would not draw any current from it either, so I would choose some FET for Q1, if it's possible...
