Interfacing digital sensors with microcontroller
I am working on a GSM SMS relay controller and I have a question about interfacing digital sensors (like motion detectors, smoke detectors, and so on) with MCU. When I see similar boards they have used optocouplers to connect these digital sensors to the microcontroller, however, these sensors have a common ground with the controller board. So we won't have isolation with optocoupler because of the common ground. My question is while there is no isolation why we do not use a simple transistor instead of an optocoupler?



Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease

An optocoupler at the input is one option to protect the microcontroller from ESD impacts. Fast high voltage transient pulses can couple through the internal capacitance of resistors and transistors at input side or just arc around them and reach the MCU input.
An optocoupler as well has a capacitance of some pF between LED and transistor, but the risk of arcing is much lower. The ESD impact still reaches the circuit, but only GND. This may introduce other issues, but will not destroy the MCU.

It is not so usual to use optocouplers with a common ground on primary and secondary side, because the main function of optocouplers is complete galvanic isolation of circuits, quite often for safety reasons.
Still, there is an advantage of using these optocouplers over using simple transistors, because there is no possibility for a current loop from the MCU to the sensor. In other words: If the MCU produces noise, the noise can not reach the sensor.
Edit: There is no galvanic coupling of noise. But noise can still couple through parasitics.

Thanks for your reply, so if I am not mistaken we will have noise reduction although there is the same grounds in both sides.

@Saeed not much, no. Stefan Wyss forgot to mention that of course, the sensor ground now becomes noisy. So, yes, the noise reaches the sensor.

@StefanWyss who says there's no current flow? In noise, you need to consider coupling of noise current through parasitics, e.g. through capacitance to some arbitrary ground plane or shield.

@StefanWyss huh? That would come as a surprise to me.
