Arduino -> PC847 optocoupler ->WS2812b RGB LED circuit isn't working
I must be doing something dumb here as my circuit tests fine yet I can't control the 5mm LED(not a strip of them).
I have a simple 1 second on/off pulse on the input pin 22. I measured pin 16 on the PC847 going from 0.16v to 4.9v as the input goes high/low as it should. Measuring the Din pin on the LED I also see the 0.16v to 4.9v pulse yet the LED does nothing.
I know the LED and the rest of the circuit works because when I remove the PC847 and jumper pins 15 and 16 the LED glows green.
What have I done wrong here?


PC847 is far too slow for this kind of signal. And the signal becomes inverted.

Thanks!
I'd inverted the signal with code but I didn't know that speed was an issue for the PC847

I'm going to use an ACPL-844

Your optocoupler is useless since both sides share ground. See more here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714850/what-is-arduino-optocoupler-disease

Is I have a simple 1 second on/off pulse on the input pin 22 a typo? The WS2812B requires a serial data stream on the DIN pin with a bit time of 1.25µs±600ns so a one second on/off pulse won't control the LEDs.

@Nismo What is the purpose of the opto in that circuit; what do you expect it to do and why? Is it for isolation? Level shifting? Inverting? Cargo-culting because every Arduino circuit must have a barely-working useless opto for coolness factor? Why would you drive 1 second pulses to a LED that requires high speed data transfer protocol?

@winny Thanks I didn't know that.

@ChesterGillon, When I just jumpered between pin 15 and 16 on the socket for the PC847  the LED would go green so I used this as a basic test. I'm guessing that was a bad idea?

@Justme I'm using an Arduino to control the gauge lights in the dashboard of my project car. The Arduino monitors the sensors and light switches and controls the gauges accordingly. I had it all going with the incandescent lights but the RPM gauge has an internal fault on the light circuit and pull about 3 amps so I'm retro fitting RGB LED's so I can have the gauge pulse red when it detects a set level so I wont need separate warning LEDs. I read about optoisolators and thought they would be the trick to protect the Arduino from what I'm reading this is not the case.

Thanks all for your help!
If I sound like I know fek all that's because it's true. I tried googling but google seems to be hard to find specific info now days.
